# Servlet context and Session in Camel Spring remoting via JMS

Tags: spring, apache-camel, httpsession, spring-remoting, spring-session

I'm trying to integrate 2 spring-mvc applications using Camel-Spring-remoting via JMS/ActiveMQ component.

I'm successfully able to call a remote method in App1 from App2.

App1 and App2 has Shared Web Sessions (using Spring-Session/Redis) which has data like currentUserId and it's properties. The call the session something like below:

```
ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
HttpSession session = attributes.getRequest().getSession(false);
session.getSession().getAttribute("SYSTEM_USER_ACCOUNT");
```

Because the remoting method calling is happening via JMS, App1 is not able to identify the previously authenticated HTTP session and  I'm getting below exception in App1

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1556)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInvocation.invoke(BeanInvocation.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:134)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at com.keype.hawk.core.api.system.util.SessionUtils.getSession(SessionUtils.java:38)
    at com.keype.hawk.core.api.system.util.SessionUtils.getSystemUserAccount(SessionUtils.java:104)
    at com.keype.hawk.core.api.system.util.SessionUtils.getStaffId(SessionUtils.java:98)
    at com.keype.hawk.core.impl.party.service.PartyServiceImpl.preUpdate(PartyServiceImpl.java:208)
    at com.keype.hawk.core.impl.party.service.PartyServiceImpl.updateParty(PartyServiceImpl.java:525)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

What's the practice here ? How can I access the servlet context and current user's http-session from within a JMS call ?